# Using foldl to remove repetitions of a list

Tags: haskell

I wrote this function to take out repetitions from a list:

```
compress :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
compress [] = []
compress [x] = [x]
compress (x:xs) = [x] ++ (compress $ filter (/=x) xs)
```

I'm now trying to use foldl to do the same thing:

```
compress' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> [a]
compress' [] = []
compress' [x] = [x]
compress' (x:xs) = foldl (\(x,y) -> if x==y then x ++ y else x ++ []) [] xs
```

but I get

```
   * Couldn't match expected type `([a1], [a1])'
                  with actual type `[a0]'
    * In the second argument of `foldl', namely `[]'
      In the expression:
        foldl (\ (x, y) -> if x == y then x ++ y else x ++ []) [] xs
      In an equation for compress':
          compress' (x : xs)
            = foldl (\ (x, y) -> if x == y then x ++ y else x ++ []) [] xs
   |
83 | compress' (x:xs) = foldl (\(x,y) -> if x==y then x ++ y else x ++ []) [] xs
```

Why it expects the type of `[]` to be `[a1],[a1]` if `foldl` can be used like this:

```
foldr f z []     = z
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things wrong in this example.

First, your lambda function is of the form:

```
([a], [a]) -> [a]
```

`foldl` expects the form `a -> b -> a`.

When using lambdas that take multiple arguments you don’t wrap them up in a tuple. Otherwise the lambda assumes it’s going to receive a tuple.

You should use the form `\x y -> ...` instead.

This is where you are receiving the error from.

The second issue you have is the `x` you refer to is not the one on the left hand side of the equals sign `(x:xs)`.  It’s actually whatever gets passed into the lambda function (the accumulator in this case). By doing it this way you actually lose the reference to the `x` you are searching for.

The third issue is, that this doesn’t do what your first function does. You only check for repetition of the head element and no others.